# Getting STL_LOAD_ERRORS duplicated while executing copy command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

While executing COPY command to get data from S3 to redshift table. The rows with errors are present in STL_LOAD_ERRORS table but they are entries are duplicated.

In STL_LOAD_ERRORS details are present for the errored rows. While executing above case getting load errors in STL_LOAD_ERROR table but errored rows are duplicated.

Comment: Exactly duplicated?  Do you have ignore errors on?  Are you directly issuing the COPY or is it delivered through a tool that possibly have a retry value?  As you can see there are a number of ways this can happen.  Please provide lines from stl_load_errors, COPY command as issued, and information about your environment to received better responses.

Comment: Most possibly this is the issue https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redshift-fix-copy-analyze-statupdate-off/


https://www.integrate.io/blog/how-to-use-redshifts-copy-command/

Looking into it !!